# Honors point count for holding all four aces in one hand?

Tags: bridge

Recently, I had a friend say that the rules for points accrued for holding all four aces in one hand have changed. I have always understood that the player received 150 points only if the contract is in no-trump.

She says that the rules have changed so that the points are awarded in any contract, even a trump contract.

Is that a recent change?

Answer (score 2):

No, this has never changed in the [Laws of Rubber Bridge (2014)](https://cdn.acbl.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Laws-of-Rubber-Bridge.pdf).

> For holding all four aces in one hand at a no trump contract: 150

In a suit contract the only scoring honours are a holding of four or five of the top five trumps.

From ***Law 81 - Scoring Table***:

[image]